# Installation of OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, opencv

I built OpenCV from Source but I can't manage to use it. Every time I try to even load an image with the next code I get `No module named cv2.cv`. Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

```
from cv2.cv import *

img = LoadImage("/home/User/Desktop/Image.png")
NamedWindow("opencv")
ShowImage("opencv",img)
WaitKey(0)
```

The procedure I did was the following...

I downloaded the zip file from the main page of GitHub and while being in a destination directory I created, I built OpenCV using

`cmake OpenCV_Source_Directory`

Then on the destination directory I run

`make`

`sudo make install`

Comment: Are you using the python version? (If so did you make sure you installed the correct version?)

Comment: @ChrisBritt I didn't know that there were multiple versions but I just downloaded the zip file from the main GitHub page and then did what I described :/

Comment: When you do cmake, and it spits out its configuration options, what does it say in the python section? (Also what version of python are you using)

Comment: @ChrisBritt Where can I see those options?

Comment: When you first run cmake

Comment: @ChrisBritt I understand that but now that I have already run it where do I find it?

Comment: Not really sure what your asking, just rerun cmake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I had to install `python-opencv` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

After that OpenCV works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely installed opencv 3, which doesn't have the `cv2.cv` module. It's all in `cv2` now.

To verify run this in a python interpreter

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

Anything like `3.0.0` or `3.1.0` means that the `cv2.cv` module doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Presumable you did:

```
git clone git@github.com:opencv/opencv.git
mkdir build; cd build
cmake ../opencv && make && sudo make install
```

But if you do this:

```
cd opencv
git describe
```

You will get something like

```
3.1.0-1374-g7f14a27
```

That is, the default branch is OpenCV 3, which doesn't have the cv2.cv module.
Either change your code to work with the OpenCV 3 cv2 module.
Or downgrade to OpenCV2. You can do this by:

```
cd opencv
git checkout 2.4.13.1
cd ../build && so on ...
```

Comment: I am just trying to run a simple example. I tried to import only the cv2 module and the same happened...What module should I use instead of the cv2?

Comment: If you build OpenCV and it can't find the python .so, it will not build the cv2 module. Did you build python yourself? If so make sure you use the `--enable-shared` option with `configure` when building python. If you didn't build python, when building opencv try `cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`   (correct that path if necessary)